# ASP.Net MVC: Partial view not rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am bit new in asp.net mvc. i am facing problem for very basic things that my Partial view not rendering. here is the details

i have a main page and one partial view

### main page action look like

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

main index view look like

```
@model Testing.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="row">

</div>

<div class="row">
    <div id="formsIndex">
    @{
        Html.Partial("_TestForm");
    }
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
       <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
}
```

here i am showing a partial view like this way `Html.Partial("_TestForm");` but no UI comes for partial view.

partial view code look like

```
@model Testing.Models.Employee

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "formsIndex" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

when i pass model to partial view this way `Html.Partial("_TestForm", Model);` then also no UI comes.

please tell me where i made the mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in method return PartialView() and try this

```
@Html.Partial("_TestForm");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Html.Partial` inside a `@{ ... }` block will just call the method and throw the result away.

You should call it outside of a `@{ ... }` block, prefixed with `@`, and remember to pass in the model:

```
<div id="formsIndex">
@Html.Partial("_TestForm", Model);
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Render like this

```
@Html.Action("_Partialview", "controllerName")
```

also create action methode of partial view

```
public ActionResult _Partialview
{
    Employee _objModel= new Employee ()
    return PartialView(_objModel);
}
```